# What does: r, g, b, *a = img_list[generated_number]: mean in python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, porting

```
r, g, b, *a = img_list[generated_number]
```

What does this means in python3? I'm porting the stegano library to python 2 (since burgled-batteries has trouble with libraries in python3 while importing from sbcl).

Is there a way of converting this notation to python 2 notation (like how type annotation can be overcome with `import typing` and `x.__annotations__ = {}`)? More generally, what is this supposed to signify? Since it raises a syntax error when run on python 2.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that question is not about iterable unpacking.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but the accepted answer does cover it - see section starting *"In Python 3 it is possible to use `*l` on the left side of an assignment"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I found a better dupe, specific to the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an iterable unpacking assignment with a catch-all component; the first 3 values are assigned to `r`, `g` and `b` respectively, the remainder of the values are assigned as a sequence to `*a` (catching any values beyond the first 3).

To achieve the same in Python 2, you'll need to use slicing:

```
(r, g, b), a = img_list[generated_number][:3], img_list[generated_number][3:]
```

See [PEP 3132 -- *Extended Iterable Unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for details on the new feature.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes. Sorry for the (as it turns out) fairly stupid question.